# string manipulation using sed like js string?

Tags: string, sed, cmd

I am writing a script where I want to access a file and update the json using sed.
for example I am using `sed -i -e '/"image": "{{ image }}",/a   "test_uuid": "{{ INSTANCE_UUID }}",' ${HOME_DIR}/common/guest_info.json` where INSTANCE_UUID is a variable which has the uuid.
I recently started using sed.
Is it possible to manipulate like JS. For example: `'test_uuid: ' + INSTANCE_UUID + ','`

PS: I tried searching for similar questions, maybe I am using the wrong keyword or something but I couldn't find any helpful resources. That's why asked the questions.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: IMHO, experts always advise to use tool like `jq` which understand json well. Could you please do let us know if you have jq installed in your system? or you can install it in your system? Solutions could be given as per that, thank you

Comment: yes. I have jq installed in the system.